# How to implement promise for http get request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following http get request:-

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'getData.php',
    params: {bill: 'Active'}
})
.then(function (response) {
    bill=response.data.results;
});
```

The request is made multiple times and I want for the processing to wait until all the http requests are done. For this I want to implement promises and then return promises at the end of the function. How can I implement promises around this http get request?

Comment: See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[];
arr.push(callHttp());
arr.push(callHttp());
arr.push(callHttp());

promise.all(arr).then(....)


function callHttp(){
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'getData.php',
    params: {bill: 'Active'}
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request (everything before the `.then(...)`) already *is* a promise.

Put your array of requests in [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get a new promise that finishes once everything is done.